# R download.file() returning 403 Forbidden error

Tags: r, web-scraping, r-download.file

The code below used to work, but the website i'm trying to download files from has added a user validation step. I've tried a couple things, including asking the code to sleep in the loop step, but nothing has worked so far. any advice?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


page <-
 "https://burnsville.civicweb.net/filepro/documents/25657/" %>%
  read_html

df <- tibble(
  names1 = page %>%
    html_nodes(".document-link") %>%
    html_text2() %>%
    str_remove_all("\r") %>%
    str_squish(),
  links = page %>%
    html_nodes(".document-link") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0("https://burnsville.civicweb.net", .)
)

destfile<-("destination.pdf")

df %>% 
  map(~ download.file(df$links, destfile = paste0(df$names1, ".pdf")))

#loop through and download PDFs
for (i in df$links) {
  tryCatch({
    download.file(url,
                  basename(url),
                  mode = "wb",
                  quiet=TRUE)
  }, error = function(e){})
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page <-
  "https://burnsville.civicweb.net/filepro/documents/25657/" %>%
  read_html

docs <- tibble(
  names = page %>%
    html_nodes(".document-link") %>%
    html_text2() %>%
    str_remove_all("\r") %>%
    str_squish(),
  links = page %>%
    html_nodes(".document-link") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0("https://burnsville.civicweb.net", .), 
  file = str_extract(links, "[^/]*$")
)

map2(docs$links, docs$file, ~ download.file(url = .x, 
                                            destfile = str_c(.y, ".pdf"), 
                                            mode = "wb"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom! Im no longer getting the 403 error, but for some reason all of the downloaded files are empty when I open them in adobe reader. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @scotiaboy Could you try now? I forgot `mode = "wb"`. The documents have content and is fine on my end.

Comment: Hello Tom, I tried your same solution for a similar website (https://gibsons.civicweb.net/document/) but I am getting the 403 forbidden error again.. any idea why that might be? This new website has the files embedded in subfolders, so im going about it slightly differently, but still using map2 at the end